# pandas not showing in conda list but I can import it

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to understand why in the conda environment that i have created,

```
conda create --name simulation python=3.6
```

i am able to import pandas without any error

```
import pandas as pd
```

However, when i execute

```
conda list
```

"pandas" dont show in the installed packages. Shouldn't my import statement fail with module not found error?
See image below:

[image]